# pass razor variable to angular function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

razor code 
`@{string razorVar= "test";}`

HTML
`<div ng-class="{active:vm.testSelected(@razorVar)}"> ...</div>`

angular controller function 
`vm.testSelected = function(jsVar) {
        return jsVar== 'test';
    }`

`jsVar` is always `undefined`

**Question**
What is the correct way to pass this `razorVar` to my function? (I do not want to use an ng-init)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup generated from your code is

```
<div ng-class="{active:vm.testSelected(test)}"> ...</div>
```

So the javascript engine is going to assume that `test` is a javascript variable. But since you did not define a javascript variable called test earlier in the page, it will be **undefined**.

Pass the value  as a string

```
<div ng-class="{active:vm.testSelected('@razorVar')}"> ...</div>
```

Now the markup generated will be

```
<div ng-class="{active:vm.testSelected('test')}"> ...</div>
```

And your `testSelected` method will get a valid string value in `jsVar` parameter.